# How to convert list of bigrams into separated bigrams in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, n-gram

I am creating a dataframe and am pulling words from another dataframe. The original dataframe I am pulling from, let's call this df_old contains two fields, ID and a question. I parse the question field of the dataframe to get a list of words, and I separate these words into separate columns, so there is one word per column. Here is the python code I used to do that:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'ID': df_old['ID'],
                  'Words':df_old['What animals are in your zoo']
                 })
#df with split list
df = pd.merge(df, pd.DataFrame(df['Words'].values.tolist()).add_prefix('word_'), on=df.index)
```

This is the output of the dataframe that I get:

```
ID    Words                     Word 1  Word 2 Word 3 
123  (dog, cat, mouse, bug)     dog      cat   mouse    
456  (penguin, whale, goldfish) penguin  whale goldfish
```

Now, I want to do the same thing for bigrams instead of unigrams.

I have a list of bigrams in the following format in my dataframe:

```
ID    Words                     Bigrams
123  (dog, cat, mouse, bug)     (dog,cat) (cat,mouse) ...   
456  (penguin, whale, goldfish) (penguin, whale) ...
```

How do I get the dataframe in the following format?

```
ID    Words                     Bigram 1  Bigram 2 ...
123  (dog, cat, mouse, bug)     (dog,cat) (cat,mouse) ...   
456  (penguin, whale, goldfish) (penguin, whale) ...
```

I used the same exact code that I used to construct the df for the unigrams. Here is the code:

```
df_bigram = pd.DataFrame({'id': df['ID'], 
                          'Bigrams': df['Words'].apply(lambda row: list(nltk.ngrams(row, 2)))  #This results in bigrams
                         })
df_bigram = pd.merge(df_bigram, pd.DataFrame(df_bigram['Bigrams'].values.tolist()).add_prefix('bigram_'), on=df_bigram.index)
```

However, when I run this code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len().
```

I am not sure as to why this error is happening as I am following the same process I did to do for creating the dataframe for the unigrams

Comment: I edited the question to make  it a bit easier to read.

Comment: I get `df_old is not defined` when I try to run your code. will you please include it?